# Redmine, wiki и несколько версий разветвленной документации

Tags: redmine

К текущему проекту, который ведется на редмайне, потребовалось написать и опубликовать онлайн-документацию на текущую и разрабатываемую версии API. По-человечески это можно сделать только в вики, используя префиксы типа API-10_ для дочерних страниц каждой из версий, чего хотелось бы избежать (ну или делать отдельный проект под каждую версию, что тоже не очень ок). Есть ли грамотный способ организовать это дело в редмайне или какое-то веб-приложение, с которым это можно будет просто реализовать (развернуть лишнее пхп-приложение - не проблема)?

Comment: Почему плохо так делать?вполне нормальная практика создавать новые страницы под каждую версию.
Общие вещи можно писать на отдельных страницах и втыкать их в создаваемые страницы через макросы типа include

!{{include(projectname:foo)}}

Comment: @pincher1519 мне все равно не очень нравится этот вариант, но сделаю так. Если хотите, можете сделать комментарий ответом - я его приму.

Comment: @Fike, А как вы ожидаете? В Вашем вопросе только притензии, что это не удобно, но не понятно, что вы ждете, в каком виде?.

Comment: @pincher1519 либо удобный способ запихнуть это все в один проект без префиксов, либо отдельное приложение, которое позволит сделать то же самое. Последний вариант был бы вообще шикарен, потому что эта задача и без редмайна может вылезти.

Comment: @Foike, посмотрите в сторону плагина База знаний. Она общая для все проектов.
Есть плагин, позволяющий крепить файлы к проекту, указанием принадлежности к версии. Имена могу только в понедельник сказать. Если сами найдёте - хорошо. 
А вообще, хорошо бы более подробно изложить бизнесспроцесс. Непростая задача режмайн внедрять. Мы уже год внедряем и достраиваем его до необходимых возможностей ...

Comment: @pincher1519, вот про плагины даже не догадался подумать, спасибо. В данный момент уже сделал на отдельных проектах (т.к. горит), но в следующий раз покопаюсь.

У нас тут все не так красиво, как обстоит на словах, и редмайн не то что внедряется, а существует главным образом для меня, потому что остальные не понимают, зачем он вообще нужен, да и апи сейчас выглядит как просто ведро несвязанных и неуклюжих методов. Не внедрение, а я просто с ним учусь обращаться )

Comment: Наверняка вопрос уже неактуален. Но вообще, OpenAPI (Swagger) и RAML.